# How to have a vertical collectionView on top of a tableView in the same scrollView programmatically?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

So I have a vertical collectionView using `CompositionalLayout` and a tableView.

How can I add the collectionView on top of the tableView?

So that the user would scroll down the collectionView and when reached the bottom of it scroll down the tableView?

I tried to put them both in a stackView, with `fillEqually` but that would just the screen in two with two individual scrolls.

Comment: you have to wrap collectionView and tableView up, inside a scrollView, then using its contentSize to fit height. However, in this way, you will miss tableView/collectionView reuseable.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just define all the view to be a collection view with custom layout? Im sure you can achieve the same ui. You can also try wrapping them in a scroll view but this approach has its own difficulties

Comment: So the last cell would be the tableView?
What about create a footerView and put the tableView inside?

Comment: No, work just with a UICollectionView and for each section have a custom layout... In this way the first section for example can be small cells and the other section can have wide cells that covers the whole width of the screen - in these way you can have a single scroll view with different cells and layout... maybe https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/layouts/customizing_collection_view_layouts and https://medium.com/@pramodmanjunath/custom-uicollectionview-layouts-a-sneak-peak-ccf8c3979569 for insperation